# Motivation for the heap lifecycle to be different from the stack lifecycle

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory

Working with C++, I have to ask some language semantics about the stack vs the heap. Firstly when we create an object on the stack it's very clear how long its life cycle is. Once it exits the {} scope operator then it is handled by the compiler and destroyed.
This is fine.

When we create an object on the heap using the new keyword, the motivation being the object itself is too large to be placed on the stack. Why then do we then have different lifecycle semantics for the heap object. Suddenly the heap object has a lifecycle of the program rather than the local scope.

Now ignoring that smart pointers handle the concept of ownership for these heap objects in much the same way as stack objects. That being when the smart pointer falls out of scope so does the object its pointing to.

What I'm asking is what/why is the motivation to give heap objects a different lifecycle than stack objects.

Comment: `the motivation being the object itself is too large to be placed on the stack` I think the motivation here is to provide developers with a mean to create objects that can exist beyond the current block scope

Comment: "Suddenly the heap object has a lifecycle of the program rather than the local scope." — *This*, not the size, is the entire point of it, and why we use the terms "dynamic storage duration" and "automatic storage duration".

Comment: PC computer programs work as they do mostly out of tradition and for backwards-compatibility reasons, rather than because of some sensible rationale. The heap was always a very badly designed part of computer programs, but it has been like that since the early days of Unix in the 1970s and people are too narrow-minded to question if it makes sense at all in the first place. Instead, computer scientists come up with even worse designs such as smart pointers and garbage collection, ie "lipstick on a pig", instead of re-desgining the whole 1970s fiasco from scratch.

Comment: Specifically, I posted a long list of valid critique [here](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121) - this was written for embedded systems, but most of it applies 100% to PC systems too. There's for example no sane reason why someone would want a PC program to behave in non-deterministic ways. "It's just a PC so we can accept some bugs and crashes" isn't a professional attitude.

Comment: Stack is faster while Heap is slower.

Answer (score 6):

It has nothing to do with size.

The sole purpose of heap objects is that they have a different lifecycle than stack objects. With the heap you can dynamically create and destroy objects at runtime, whenever you feel like it. You could pass an object on the heap from one block to another and transfer ownership to that different block, where with a stack object you would be bound to the lifetime of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine very simple function which allocated the memory for the int array and sets the random values to its elements.

```
int *createArray(size_t size)
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * size);
    if(x)
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) x[index] = rand();
    return x;
}
```

The caller can use this array as its lifetime is not limited to the function scope.

If I modify it to use automatic storage duration array, if the caller tries to use the returned reference, it will invoke UB as the array is accessed outside the function scope:

```
int *createArray(size_t size)
{
    int x[size];
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) x[index] = rand();
    return x;
}
```